# In cakephp2.7.7 i got error as "Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred."

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have this error while upload the image file into some other folder.

> "Error: An  Internal Error Has Occurred."..!!

This code get all details of uploaded image like size, temp name, etc..
but it shows the error in internal and also image not uploaded to the given dir..

This is my upload component code; file name is UploadComponent.php:

```
<?php
    App::uses('Component','Controller');
    class UploadComponent extends Component
    {
    public function upload($data=null)
    {
        if(!empty($data))
        {
                foreach($data AS $file)// use for each for multiple upload
        {
            $filename= $file['name'];
            $file_tmp_name = $file['temp_name'];
            $dir = WWW_ROOT.'img'.DS.'uploads';
            $allowed = array('png','jpg','jpeg','bmp');
            if(!in_array(substr(strrchr($filename,'.'),1), $allowed))
            {
                throw new NotFoundException("Error Processing Request", 1);
            }elseif (is_uploaded_file($file_temp_name))
            {
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name, $dir.DS.String::uuid().'-'.$filename);
            }
        }
        }
      }
     }
```

In controller I just call the upload component and I didn't create any database. Here it take the count data value as "5", even I choose one file. 
This is the code for controller "ImagesController"

view part I create a folder name as Images and file name as upload.ctp
It is a view:

```
 <?php echo $this->Form->create('Image', array('type'=>'file')); ?>
      <?php
  echo $this->Form->file('uploadfile', array('multiple'));
 echo $this->Form->end('Image');
 ?>
```

So any one please help for this problem and suggest any solutions. The error shows in the component only. I think it have a problem on input of the file that get from view(upload.ctp).

Comment: Turn debugging on with `Configure::write('debug', 2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Deprecated since version 2.7: The String class was deprecated in 2.7 in favour of the CakeText class. While the String class is still available for backwards compatibility, using CakeText is recommended as it offers compatibility with PHP7 and HHVM.

Use `CakeText::uuid();`

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/string.html